# Obtaining all possible combinations with a minimum number per group

Tags: r

Apologies for lack of a reproducible example as I'm not too sure how to code this.

Let's say I have four groups: `red`, `yellow`, `green`, and `blue`.

I have fifteen marbles to distribute to each group, with a constraint that each group must have at least two marbles. How can I get all possible combinations that can be allotted to each group? My desired end result is a data frame along the following lines, where the number represents the number of marbles allocated to that group:

```
combo_id   red   yellow   green   blue
1          3     3        5       4
2          3     5        4       3
3          5     2        5       3
```

And so on until all combinations have been enumerated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

colors <- c("red", "yellow", "green", "blue")
names(colors) <- colors

all_possible_combinations <- expand.grid(map(colors, function(x) 2:9))

all_possible_combinations$sum <- rowSums(all_possible_combinations)

# Get all distributions that sum to 15 and therefore give out all marbles
all_possible_combinations %>%
  filter(sum == 15) %>%
  as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 120 × 5
#>      red yellow green  blue   sum
#>    <int>  <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#>  1     9      2     2     2    15
#>  2     8      3     2     2    15
#>  3     7      4     2     2    15
#>  4     6      5     2     2    15
#>  5     5      6     2     2    15
#>  6     4      7     2     2    15
#>  7     3      8     2     2    15
#>  8     2      9     2     2    15
#>  9     8      2     3     2    15
#> 10     7      3     3     2    15
#> # … with 110 more rows

# Include combinations where some of the marbles might be retained.
all_possible_combinations %>%
  filter(sum <= 15) %>%
  as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 330 × 5
#>      red yellow green  blue   sum
#>    <int>  <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
#>  1     2      2     2     2     8
#>  2     3      2     2     2     9
#>  3     4      2     2     2    10
#>  4     5      2     2     2    11
#>  5     6      2     2     2    12
#>  6     7      2     2     2    13
#>  7     8      2     2     2    14
#>  8     9      2     2     2    15
#>  9     2      3     2     2     9
#> 10     3      3     2     2    10
#> # … with 320 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks @Till. Question - is this syntax correct: `all_possible_combinations <- expand.grid(map(colors, \(x) 2:6))`. I get the following error message when I run it: `Error: unexpected input in "all_possible_combinations <- expand.grid(map(colors, \"`

Comment: You truncated the error message there, but my guess is that this is due to your R version being to old. The `\(x)` function definition shorthand was introduced recently. I changed it to `function(x)`, please try again.

Comment: Actually, why not the new R 4.1.0 pipe, `|>`? Even replace `filter` for `subset` and have an entirely base R solution! (Not clear where `purrr` is used). And reconsider naming objects as built-in functions like `sum`.

Comment: Thanks! What I ended up using was `expand.grid(map(1:4, function(x) 2:9)) %>% setNames(c("red", "yellow", "green", "blue")) %>% filter(rowSums(.[1:4]) == 15)`

Answer (score 4):

I think you can achieve this using `permuteGeneral` from the `RcppAlgos` package.

Stating the problem as: what permutations of 4 numbers in the range 2-9 sum to 15. If the minimum per group is 2 then the maximum per group has to be 9, since 2 + 2 + 2 + 9 = 15.

```
library(RcppAlgos)
dataset <- permuteGeneral(2:9, 
                          m = 4, 
                          TRUE, 
                          constraintFun = "sum", 
                          comparisonFun = "==", 
                          limitConstraints = 15)

head(dataset)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    2    2    9
[2,]    2    2    9    2
[3,]    2    9    2    2
[4,]    9    2    2    2
[5,]    2    2    3    8
[6,]    2    2    8    3

nrow(dataset)
[1] 120
```

To get a data frame:

```
dataset <- as.data.frame(dataset)
names(dataset) <- c("red", "yellow", "green", "blue")
```

Comment: I compared this answer to mine in regards to performance. This answer scales much better. For the example given both answers return instant results. When you divide between more than six groups my answer becomes slow, at 12 groups it runs out of memory, while this answer still returns results immediately.